# Is there a way to get number of elements from object?

Tags: javascript

Let me explain in detail. I have below an object with me -

```
{
    "OBJECT1" : {
        "NAME1" : "VALUE1",
        "NAME2" : "VALUE2",
        "NAME3" : "VALUE3"
     },
     "OBJECT2" : {
        "NAME4" : "VALUE4",
        "NAME5" : "VALUE5"
     }
}
```

From this object, I want to get something like number of elements in OBJECT1 = 3 and number of elements in OBJECT2 = 2. If at all this is possible using javascript.
Basically what I am trying to do is, to loop through the name value pairs available in the object dynamically so that if someone adds another element to object, I don't have to change my code.

Also any alternative is also ruled out since I am allowed to only use object in my use-case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Length of Javascript Associative Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-javascript-associative-array)

Comment: Those objects are not called JSON objects. JSON is only a notation, that represents *JavaScript* objects.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: so, is it possible to say that such JSON string as we see here is a serialized form of a JS object?

Comment: @Korpel - Yeah, even I am curious to know answer for Piskvor's question. Coz in our project, we store such objects in a ".json" file and do a fileparse to get the object in our javascript source code. Hence I thought these were called JSON objects.

Comment: @Piskvor and Sachin: Correct. There is no such thing as a ‘JSON object’. When those JSON strings are parsed, they are ‘interpreted’ to generate a true (native) JavaScript object (remember JSON is an abbreviation of ‘JavaScript Object Notation’). That's also why I deleted the [json] tag: the question *is* about a JavaScript object, which is showed to us in JSON format (which is completely sound, BTW).

Comment: @Korpel - Thank you very much for this helpful insight, this is like getting 2 answers in one shot ;)

Comment: Just one more thing: you're ‘calling’ me by my surname, but that doesn't notify me. Please read [How do comment replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) to see how to do this correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without converting your object you could iterate through the object counting properties like so:

```
function countObjectProperties(obj)
{
    var count = 0;
    for(var i in obj)
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i))
            count++;

    return count;
}
```

Expanding on why you need to use [hasOwnProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/328kyd6z(VS.85).aspx) as I said in the comment below you can run into an issue where a library or browser has added methods and properties to Objects, in order to avoid counting these we check for [hasOwnProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/328kyd6z(VS.85).aspx) before counting it. [More details at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/328kyd6z(VS.85).aspx) or at [Mozilla Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Comment: why is hasOwnProperty necessary (just asking) ?

Comment: @Samuel_xL You need hasOwnProperty to avoid counting functions, and other unwanted builtins the the browser and/or plugins might have added.

Answer (score 4):

For JSON string that represent an **object** (which is your case), you cannot use any length property. you need to loop through the object (see Kristoffer S Hansen's answer).

If it represented an **array**, you could get the length with:

```
var len = arr.length;
```

JQuery makes it simpler:

```
var len = $(JSON).length;
```

Comment: No Jquery please and also I am supposed to avoid eval in my project standards.

Comment: eval was for the array example, which you don't need anyway. It was just additional information :) Ok I've removed eval since it's off-topic.

Comment: Don’t use `eval` if not necessary.

Comment: Currently, my JSON object is just NAME VALUE pairs as in the example above. I am not sure if looping thru all elements in object is possible or not. just in case its not possible, then maybe I need to move NAME VALUE pairs into an array from where I can use the length and loop through.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your broader goal, as specified in your question:

For looping through the properties, you can use the for..in construct:

```
for (var item in myobject) {
  // some browsers add more properties to every object, we don't want those
  if (myobject.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
    do_something(item);
  }
}
```

Assuming that `myobject` is the object in your question, this will loop through it and call `do_something(OBJECT1)` and `do_something(OBJECT2)`; you can use the same construct to loop through the child objects:

```
// loop through OBJECT1 and OBJECT2
for (var item in myobject) {
  // some browsers add more properties to every object, we don't want those
  if (myobject.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
    // loop through the item's children
    for (var pair in item) {
      if (item.hasOwnProperty(pair)) {
        // each of the name:value pairs will be passed to this
        do_something_else(item,pair);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In the second snippet it seems that `item` is already the *key* of each key-value pair, so it makes no sense to iterate over it again...

Comment: @Timwi: Actually, no: in the outer loop, we iterate over the top-level properties, i.e. OBJECT1 and OBJECT2. In the inner loop, we iterate over *their* properties, i.e. NAME1,NAME2,NAME3, and NAME4, NAME5, respectively. If the nesting went further, we could be iterating over the deeper objects (maybe recursion could be used).

Comment: To clarify, in the second loop I'm iterating the properties of a property of the top-level object (`myobject.OBJECT1.NAME1` etc). This nesting could go deeper, but doesn't in this case.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, for some reason I thought your second snippet was the `do_something` function the first one called inside the loop. Never mind :)